# Javascript AJAX loads one link but not another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Javascript AJAX to load pages in the centre of my page.

Below is the Javascript.

```
$(function(){
    $('#dashboard').click(function() {
        var req = $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'dashboard.php',
            dataType    : 'html'
        });
        req.done(function(data){
            $('#loadcontent').empty().append(data);
        });
    });

    $('#admin').click(function() {
        var req = $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : '/admin/index.php',
            dataType    : 'html'
        });
        req.done(function(data){
            $('#loadcontent').empty().append(data);
        });
    }); 

    $('#reports, #analytics').click(function() {
        alert('Coming Soon');
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML / CSS for the page. As it's a lot of code, I have popped it in a pastebin

http://pastebin.com/kMMBMjrZ

The 2 bits of code in particular are below:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a id="dashboard" href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a id="reports" href="#">Reports</a></li>
    <li><a id="analytics" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And the bit that doesn't work

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['isAdmin'] ) {
        echo "<li><a id='admin' href='#'>Admin</a></li>";
    }
?>
```

So at the moment, when a user selects overview, it will load the page in the centre of the index page. That's exactly what I want, however if anyone selects admin nothing happens. The console reports nothing. At first I thought it was due to the PHP but I removed this and left pure html and it made no difference.

I have another problem where the account tab button doesn't appear to work, but that can be addressed separately.

Any thoughts on this would be brilliant.

Comment: May be something wrong with your path ? Try changing this `/admin/index.php` to `admin/index.php`. Or even better, post the directories tree

Comment: What do you see in the console? Is the `$.ajax` firing? Have you tried placing an alert inside the `$('#admin').click(function() {` to make sure the binding occurs? You are only assuming that it succeed, as you never check for errors.

Comment: This did not make a difference I'm afraid :(

Comment: $('#admin').click(function() {
  var req = $.ajax({
   alert('Clicked');
   type        : 'POST',
   url         : 'admin/index.php',
   dataType    : 'html'
  });
  req.done(function(data){
   $('#loadcontent').empty().append(data);
  });
 }); 

Nothing loads in console, however it will when I click overview.

Comment: Why are you storing `$.ajax` to a var ? Try `$.ajax({ ... }).done(function(data...`

Comment: @Runt put the alert outside `$.ajax`

Comment: Moving it up 1 line didn't make a difference, will look at the other suggestion

Comment: Check the css of your surrounding elements. You may have an element that is overlaying that link, preventing you from actually clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess it's just a problem of the path , try this :

```
$('#admin').click(function() {
        var req = $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : './admin/index.php',
            dataType    : 'html'
        });
        req.done(function(data){
            $('#loadcontent').empty().append(data);
        });
});
```

however add an alert to your action to see if li is clicked or not

Comment: This did not work, and the alert reports nothing. Console is empty, so it's as if the JS is not loaded on this part of the page?

Comment: i tried in local and it's workin with that :                 url         : '../admin/index.php',

Comment: Then something is not working in my env, did you copy all the code?

Comment: yeah , did you include jquery.js in you page ??

Comment: Yes it's in the header, look at the pastebin.

Comment: I must of had it cache'd, this has solved my problem. Any tips on the other Css breaking? I guess I need a separate question for that. P.s thank you!